# Why did backcountry camping at Canyon de Chelly collapse?

Tags: camping, united-states, backcountry

Looking at [Canyon de Chelly backcountry camping visitation by month](https://irma.nps.gov/Stats/SSRSReports/Park%20Specific%20Reports/Visitation%20by%20Month):

[image: Visitor stats]

Backcountry camping went from usually more than a hundred per month, up to several hundred per month, throughout spring, summer (except for August, which is probably too hot), and fall in the 2000-2017 period, then collapsed to just a handful per month in 2018 (and with August now the most popular month!).  What happened?  Did it become nearly prohibited?

Or did they just stop counting or change definitions?

Comment: It looks like its just a matter of how the visits are categorized. tent camping dropped off after 2012 but that's because it was turned over to contracters

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Whatever happened, it happened for good. Leave the place alone! :D

Comment: You would think it is almost certainly new restrictions by the Navajo Parks Dept, but the numbers for 2018 are incredibly low for even that. I'm sure a call (928-674-2106) to them will enlighten you.